# Call Java varargs method from invokedynamic

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm, invokedynamic

I want to dynamically call a native method from Java.
Because the method signature is unknown at compile time, I've made generic native methods for most primitive return types that have the same signature:

```java
class NativeHook {
    
    public static native int callInt(String funcName, Object... funcArgs);
    public static native void callVoid(String funcName, Object... funcArgs);
    public static native Object callObject(String funcName, Object... funcArgs);

    private static MethodHandle getNativeMethod(String callName, Class<?> returnType) {
        return MethodHandles.lookup().findStatic(NativeHook.class, callName,
            MethodType.methodType(returnType, String.class, Object[].class));
    }
}
```

I'm looking to create a MethodHandle that would then call a matching `callXXX` method and pass in the boxed `funcArgs` as if they were provided individually. These `callXXX` methods can be accessed like this:

```java
MethodHandle callInt = getNativeMethod("callInt", int.class);
MethodHandle boundCallInt = callInt.bindTo("my_c_function_name").asVarargsCollector(Object[].class);

// returns NativeHook.callInt("my_c_function_name", 1, 2, 3)
boundCallInt.invokeWithArguments(1, 2, 3);
```

I'm using this bootstrap method to indirectly reference this `callXXX` method in invokedynamic, which works the same way as above:

```java
public static CallSite bootstrap(MethodHandles.Lookup caller, String name, MethodType type) {
    if (type.returnType() == int.class) {
        MethodHandle callInt = getNativeMethod("callInt", int.class);
        return new ConstantCallSite(callInt.bindTo(name).asVarargsCollector(Object[].class));
    }
}
```

The call is then done with invokedynamic like this:

```java
mv.visitIntInsn(BIPUSH, 1);
mv.visitIntInsn(BIPUSH, 2);
mv.visitIntInsn(BIPUSH, 3);
mv.visitInvokeDynamicInsn("my_c_function_name", "(III)I", NativeHook.bootstrapHandle);
```

However, this does not work as expected and throws an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.invoke.WrongMethodTypeException: MethodHandle(Object[])int should be of type (int,int,int)int
    at java.lang.invoke.CallSite.wrongTargetType(CallSite.java:194)
    at java.lang.invoke.CallSite.makeSite(CallSite.java:335)
    ... 16 more
```

How do I construct a proper MethodHandle that accepts arguments like a regular method but then calls the vararg `callXXX` method?

Comment: Writing off the top of my head, `.asVarargsCollector(Object[].class) .asType(type)` would be the right way to do it.

Comment: @Holger That is indeed the right way, thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [the package documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/package-summary.html#bsm) we find the statement

> The type of the call site's target must be exactly equal to the type derived from the invocation's type descriptor and passed to the bootstrap method.

So it is not enough to be compatible in terms of `invoke`, but it has to be compatible with `invokeExact`.

After applying `.asVarargsCollector(Object[].class)`, it is possible to `invoke` the handle, but it’s not matching the exact signature. But we can adapt it via [`asType`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.html#asType(java.lang.invoke.MethodType)):

> If the current method is a variable arity method handle argument list conversion may involve the conversion and collection of several arguments into an array, as [described elsewhere](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.html#asVarargsCollector(java.lang.Class)).

This implies that the combination of `asVarargsCollector` and `asType` should work. But we can also consider the general relationship between `invoke` and `invokeExact` mentioned in the same method documentation:

> This method provides the crucial behavioral difference between [`invokeExact`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.html#invokeExact(java.lang.Object...)) and plain, inexact [`invoke`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.html#invoke(java.lang.Object...)). The two methods perform the same steps when the caller's type descriptor exactly matches the callee's, but when the types differ, plain [`invoke`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.html#invoke(java.lang.Object...)) also calls `asType` (or some internal equivalent) in order to match up the caller's and callee's types.

In other words, if `invoke` works successfully, the `asType` conversion also must be possible to meet the requirements for `invokeExact`.

Which we can demonstrate:

```java
MethodHandles.Lookup l = MethodHandles.lookup();
MethodHandle h = l.bind(System.out, "printf",
    MethodType.methodType(PrintStream.class, String.class, Object[].class));

h = h.bindTo("%s %s %s%n").asVarargsCollector(Object[].class);

try {
    System.out.println("invoke(1, 2, 3): ");
    h.invoke(1, 2, 3);
} catch(Throwable t) {
    System.out.println(t);
}
try {
    System.out.println("\ninvokeExact(1, 2, 3): ");
    h.invokeExact(1, 2, 3);
} catch(Throwable t) {
    System.out.println(t);
}

MethodType type = MethodType.methodType(void.class, int.class, int.class, int.class);

try {
    System.out.println("\n.asType(type).invokeExact(1, 2, 3): ");
    h.asType(type).invokeExact(1, 2, 3);
} catch(Throwable t) {
    System.out.println(t);
}
```

```
invoke(1, 2, 3): 
1 2 3

invokeExact(1, 2, 3): 
java.lang.invoke.WrongMethodTypeException: expected (Object[])PrintStream but found (int,int,int)void

.asType(type).invokeExact(1, 2, 3): 
1 2 3
```

The bootstrap method does receive the required `MethodType` as third argument already, so all it needs to do, it to apply `.asType(type)` using that type.